# Python group by; keep only when condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

Let’s say you have a data set that have part, project, quote, price and `isSelected`.

For every part, project, and quote, if there is an `isSelected`, only keep that one line, but if there is no `isSelected`, then keep all lines for that part, project, and quote combination.

See example below.

Data set:

| Part | project | Quote | Price | isSelected |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 5.0 | No |
| 1 | A | 1 | 2.2 | Yes |
| 5 | C | 2 | 6.6 | No |
| 5 | C | 2 | 1.2 | Yes |
| 3 | B | 3 | 5.5 | No |
| 3 | B | 3 | 4.6 | No |

Desired result:

| Part | project | Quote | Price | isSelected |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 2.2 | Yes |
| 5 | C | 2 | 1.2 | Yes |
| 3 | B | 3 | 5.5 | No |
| 3 | B | 3 | 4.6 | No |

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing the data in a table. Unfortunately, this is not the best format for sharing data here! Usually it's better to share "raw" CSV data or something comparable, because this makes it easier for people to copy and paste in order to experiment with your data and develop a solution.

Comment: Note for readers: it turns out that you can copy the entire table. At least on my machine (Mac), it rendered as plain tab-separated data when I pasted it into my code editor (Neovim).

Comment: In your first row of output, it looks like you meant to write `1` and not `2` in the `Part` column. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This general category of task can be solved by looping over the `GroupBy` object that results from the `.groupby` operation on a `Series` or `DataFrame`.

In this particular case, you can also use the [`GroupBy.apply` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html), which performs a calculation on each group and concatenates the results together.

The documentation for the `GroupBy` class is [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/groupby.html).

I will present the looping version first, because it might be more accessible to programmers who aren't already familiar with the "DataFrame style" of computing. However, I suggest using the `.apply` version whenever you can. It will be faster when processing large datasets, and might consume less memory. It's also considered more "idiomatic" style, and it will force you to learn how to break down your code into individual functions.

#### Using a loop

A lot of people don't realize that the result of `DataFrame.groupby` (a `GroupBy` object) can be iterated over. This specific functionality is documented [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.__iter__.html).

Beyond that, the logic consists of a straightforward `if` statement, some Pandas subsetting, and the [`concat` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).

Complete example:

```py
import io
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''
Part,Project,Quote,Price,isSelected
1,A,1,5.0,No
1,A,1,2.2,Yes
5,C,2,6.6,No
5,C,2,1.2,Yes
3,B,3,5.5,No
3,B,3,4.6,No
'''))

group_results = []
for _, group in data.groupby(['Part', 'Project', 'Quote']):
    is_selected = group['isSelected'] == 'Yes'

    if is_selected.any():
        # Select the rows where 'isSelected' is True, and
        # then select the first row from that output.
        # Using [0] instead of 0 ensures that the result
        # is still a DataFrame, and that it does not get
        # "squeezed" down to a Series.
        group_result = group.loc[is_selected].iloc[[0]]

    else:
        group_result = group

    group_results.append(group_result)

results = pd.concat(group_results)
print(results)
```

Output:

```
   Part Project  Quote  Price isSelected
1     1      A       1    2.2        Yes
4     3      B       3    5.5         No
5     3      B       3    4.6         No
3     5      C       2    1.2        Yes
```

#### Using `.apply`

The `GroupBy.apply` method essentially does the `pd.concat` and list-appending part for you. Instead of writing a loop, we write a *function*, which we pass to `.apply`:

```py
import io
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''
Part,Project,Quote,Price,isSelected
1,A,1,5.0,No
1,A,1,2.2,Yes
5,C,2,6.6,No
5,C,2,1.2,Yes
3,B,3,5.5,No
3,B,3,4.6,No
'''))


groups = data.groupby(['Part', 'Project', 'Quote'], as_index=False)


def process_group(group):
    is_selected = group['isSelected'] == 'Yes'

    if is_selected.any():
        # Select the rows where 'isSelected' is True, and
        # then select the first row from that output.
        # Using [0] instead of 0 ensures that the result
        # is still a DataFrame, and that it does not get
        # "squeezed" down to a Series.
        group_result = group.loc[is_selected].iloc[[0]]

    else:
        group_result = group

    return group_result


# Use .reset_index to remove the extra index layer created by Pandas,
# which is not necessary in this situation.
results = groups.apply(process_group).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
print(results)
```

Output:

```
   Part Project  Quote  Price isSelected
1     1       A      1    2.2        Yes
4     3       B      3    5.5         No
5     3       B      3    4.6         No
3     5       C      2    1.2        Yes
```

Comment: I used your .apply Method and it worked,  thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped @BobbyPlourde ! You can mark this answer as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark next to it. This adds a visible marker to the answer, so that future readers can see that the answer worked. It also awards a some "reputation points" to the author of the answer, which I personally don't need, but it can be valuable for a user with fewer points than me.

Answer (score 0):

see if this helps:

```html
yes=[]
yesIndex=[]
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if (row['isSelected']=='Yes'):
        yes.append(row['Part'])
        yesIndex.append(index)
        
no=list(set(df.Part.unique().tolist()) - set(yes))
noIndex=[]
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if (row['Part'] in no):
        noIndex.append(index)
        
        
listofindex=yesIndex+noIndex
df.loc[df.index.isin(listofindex)]
```

Here I tried to get the Parts that has 'Yes', then compared with the unique Part list and got the list of Parts that only has 'No'. Then got the indexes for those.